# Return PHP array to JavaScript file with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

To preface this question, I have a basic understanding of PHP and AJAX. I was asked to design a simple form that would ask the user to select one of two car manufacturers, which would return all models of the selected make from the multidimensional array created in the data.php file. So far this is what I was able to come up with:

index.php

```
<body>
<form id="form">
<label for="make">
Make
<select name="make" id="make">
<option value="" selected="selected">None</option>
<option value="Ford">Ford</option>
<option value="BMW">BMW</option>
</select>
</label>
<input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<h2>Models:</h2>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

data.php

```
<?php
$data = array(
array('make' => 'Ford', 'model' => 'Fiesta'),
array(''make' => 'Ford', 'model' => 'Focus'),
array('make' => 'Ford', 'model' => 'Mustang'),
array('make' => 'BMW', 'model' => '320'),
array('make' => 'BMW', 'model' => 'X3'),
array('make' => 'BMW', 'model' => 'X5'),
);
?>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
require_once( 'data.php' );
$myJSON = json_encode($data);
echo $myJSON;
?>
```

function.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
"use strict"
console.log("Document loaded...");

$('#submit').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submit button was clicked");
    run_ajax();
});

var run_ajax = function() {
    var results = $( '#results' );
    var formData = $( '#make' );
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
          console.log("Before Send");
        },
        success: function( response ) {
          console.log("Success");
        },
    });
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var carModel;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (x in myObj) {
          console.log("testing");
          carModel += myObj[x].model + "<br>";
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = carModel;
      };
    };
};
});
```

I am able to get the Success message to display in the console but I cannot get anything to display in the 'results' div in index.php. Does anyone know where I am going wrong? I have searched related topics but couldn't find anything regarding pulling data from a local file. Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: `$.ajax` or `new XMLHttpRequest();` pick **one**

Comment: If i were to use $.ajax where would I return the array?

Comment: The array is what you have named `response` in the success handler. Add `console.log(response)` will see it. Your `XMLHttpRequest` code is incomplete without a `send()`. Stick to the $.ajax since it has error handling that you would need to write yourself otherwise or more modern `fetch()`

Comment: Thanks Quentin and charlieft! And yea charlieft I know, that's next on my list. I had a short deadline and couldn't find the resources I needed. I am getting the array to return to the console so I should be able to handle it from here!

Comment: You also show a quoting error in data.php on line 4

Comment: That was just a mistype. Thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now, thanks for the help everyone!

```
function run_ajax(make) {
    var results = $( '#results' );
    var msg = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: make,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
          console.log("Before Send");
        },
        success: function( response ) {
          console.log("Success!");
          for(var x in response) {
            if(response[x].make == make) {
              msg += response[x].model + "<br>";
            }
          }
          if(msg == "") {
            msg = "No matches found!";
          }
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = msg;
        },
    });
};
```